# Revert build process Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic4

I built an application using Ionic 4 for my android device and it runs pretty well. For some reason I lost the source of the project (not completely but most of it), so now the only possible way to retrieve it without completely rewrite it is to use the code inside the apk.

I managed to get it from the device, extract the content and locate the www folder which is obviously not that readable.

I would like to find a way to revert the build process that build the javascript from the typescript.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean restore typescript files from compiled js? Strangely i find nothing about this anywhere..

Comment: Yes, exactly what you said

Comment: Were you using a code repository?

Comment: If you mean something like git on a remote yes but for some reason I lost the last changes that I need to recover and I did not pushed.